# how to export specific column after query meets criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, workbench

i am running this query (mysql workbench) which works perfectly.

```
select * from message where date between '2001-09-09 00:00:00' and '2001-09-10 00:00:00'
```

the results of this query are a number of various columns, of which i am only interested in one named 'body'.

How do i go about exporting only the 'body' column that has resulted from the above query?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the column(s) you want after `select` instead of using `*` ("all"):

```
select body from message where date between '2001-09-09 00:00:00' and '2001-09-10 00:00:00'
```

The column(s) you select and the column(s) by which you filter can be two entirely different sets of columns.